# What's so bad about system()?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Given that you're building a Windows - exclusive program, why are calls to `system()` so hated? Ever since I started programming in C++, "don't touch system" was something I've heard an awful lot. I've obeyed that principle docilely but what's so bad about it?

Comment: Plus, the things people tend to want to put in `system()` are usually just so inane, like clearing the screen, or pausing. It tends to be used as a lazy and sub-optimal way of doing something that would be much better done in actual code.

Comment: If you do it wrong and pass unsanitized user input to it you open your application to command injection vulnerabilities. An attacker could run arbitrary commands with the same privileges as your application.

Comment: Do whatever you want, if you know what are you doing.

Comment: The problem with "if you know what you are doing" is the self-assessment aspect of it.  Sort of like saying, "Crazy people line up here, sane ones line up there."

Comment: For me, it means _"Be careful"_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you put inside the system call is dependent on the OS you will run the program on. So it's completely non-portable. Also, many things can go wrong, as you're just throwing a command into the void, and hope that everything will go fine. Error handling (for example - the program you want to run does not exist, or PATH is not set correctly, or you don't have permissions, etc.) is very hard or even impossible.

Beside this, as noted in the comments most of the time (really "most", like 99.999%) there is no need to use `system`.

Comment: "So it's completely non-portable." system(""); looks pretty portable to me

Comment: @user1233963 There may be some wacko compiler that permits top-level function calls. Otherwise, you are correct; the program "`system("");`" will portably _fail to compile_.

Comment: @user1233963 It's not portable by definition, because the result of this call depends on the OS. Also, a call for one exemplary argument doesn't imply anything about a function being portable.

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick I believe we are discussing valid programs that are portable or not, not something that won't compile. Nowhere anyone mentions "top-level function calls", whatever that is.

Comment: @user1233963 My point is, once you are being so literal that you think "completely non-portable" means "never portable at all", the program `system("");` taken literally (as opposed to `int main(){system ("");return 0;}`) would not compile.

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick But they didn't say anything about `system("");` being a program in any way, nor did they even suggest that :) The topic of this question was portability of this function, nothing more.

Comment: @BartoszKP Fair enough.

Answer (score 6):

`std::system()` requires that you trust the command to do what you want. You have no way of verifying whether this assumption is justified. For example an unusual value for the PATH environment variable may cause a different program to be executed than in the standard setup.

The behaviour of a call to `std::system()` is system dependant. Even if the requirement at the moment is, that the application does not need to run on other operating system, this requirement can change. Considering that `std::system()` is often used for purposes that can be achieved in a more portable manner (especially by beginners), introducing platform dependance here is not required.

Answer (score 2):

`system()` invokes the OS's command interpreter as a separate process.  More times than not, there are native APIs available to accomplish the same result directly within the calling process and with more control over it.