# looking for better ways to write this program c++

Tags: c++

is there a Better way to wirte this program. for addition   The program is adding a and b to get a sum. i'm looking for way to get better.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int s = 0;

int main()
{
    cout << "Type a Number: ";
    cin >> a ;
    cout << "Type another Number:"; 
    cin >> b;
    cout << "you sum is... ";
    cout << int (s = (b + a)) << endl ;
    system ("pause"); 
}
```

Comment: Dont use globals if you dont have to + dont use using namespace

Comment: What do you mean by "better way"?

Comment: ***int (s = (b + a))*** Don't write code like this. Calculate the sum on a separate line.

Comment: Your question might be better asked at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: ***using namespace std;*** Avoid using this.

Comment: ***system ("pause");*** There are outher ways of getting around this IDE limitation.

Comment: Avoid `std::system` ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468578/whats-so-bad-about-system)). Avoid `using namespace std;` ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)).

Comment: You can get rid of the `s` variable and use `std::cout << (b + a) << "\n";`.

Comment: Try using better names for your variables, like `sum` instead of `s`.

Comment: so would i use a structure for the variables

Comment: Put them in `main()`. And give them more meaningful names. Then research the other suggestions on this site. Most are duplicates that are asked / discussed very frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
  int a=0,b=0,sum=0;
  cout<<"Type a and b"<<endl;
  cin>>a>>b;
  sum=a+b;
  cout<<sum<<endl;
  return 0;
 }
```